# Form submit Marketo issue

Tags: javascript, forms, lightbox, marketo

I am trying to modify some copy in a div on a webpage on successful submission of my form. I am using Marketo Webforms 2.0 (which I don't know that well). My form lightbox loads correctly on the onclick event, but when I try to change the innerHTML of the div that I am targeting (I am using the word "goodbye" for now), it does so briefly, before reverting to the original. 
I tried to use "return false" which allowed the innerHTML to work on the target div, but then I was unable to close the form lightbox onSuccess. Any help with this is much appreicated. My code is below:

```
<pre>
<div id="formTrigger">form Trigger</div>
<script src="//app-sjo.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
<form id="mktoForm_1290"></form>
<script>
var formTrigger = document.getElementById("formTrigger");
var myForm = document.getElementById("mktoForm_1290");
formTrigger.onclick = function (){
MktoForms2.loadForm("//app-sjo.marketo.com", "044-BGV-765", 1290, function (form){
MktoForms2.lightbox(form).show();
console.log(form);
form.onSuccess(function(){
formTrigger.innerHTML = "Goodbye";
lightbox.hide();
return false;
});
});
}
</script>
</pre>
```